# Is it possible to define default value in Sequelize migration?

Tags: node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js

There is no documentation details about addColumn options, so I'm trying this:

```
queryInterface.addColumn('OrderBackups', 'my_column', Sequelize.INTEGER, { defaultValue: 0 })
```

and it does not work.
ps: I'm using postgres

Answer (score 49, accepted):

So syntax for this is

```
queryInterface.addColumn('OrderBackups', 'my_column', {
  type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
  defaultValue: 0
})
```

Comment: Check this guide [addColumn](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/class/lib/query-interface.js~QueryInterface.html#instance-method-addColumn)

Answer (score 1):

addColumn method doesn't support defaultValue option for Postgres. It only works for MSSQL. Check [these](https://sequelize.org/v5/class/lib/query-interface.js%7EQueryInterface.html#instance-method-addColumn) docs

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old topic. However, after pulling my hair out for a while, something sequelize causes much of, I got it done. Basically, it's just easier using SQL:

```js
'use strict'
const tableName = 'my_table'
const columnName = 'count'
const { sequelize } = require('../models')

module.exports = {
  up: async (queryInterface, Sequelize) => {
    const sql = `ALTER TABLE IF EXISTS public.${tableName} ADD COLUMN ${columnName} integer NOT NULL DEFAULT 1;`
    const [results, metadata] = await sequelize.query(sql, {type: sequelize.QueryTypes.RAW})
  },

  down: async (queryInterface, Sequelize) => {
    await queryInterface.removeColumn(tableName, columnName)
  },
}
```